# How to save country-specific bank details?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, banking

I am currently developing a rails application which should accept country-specific bank account details.

For example:

```
German Bank Details:
Kontoinhalber: Alice Springs
Kontonummer: 1234567
Bankleitzahl: 111111111

French Bank Details:
Numéro de compte: 0987654
Clé RIB: 123
Code banque: 12345
Code guichet: 1234
```

How can I save this different formats to the database? Furthermore how can I display different input fields for this?

Comment: Seems like a good candidate for Single Table Inheritance. All banks have at least some fields in common; some may have some extra fields.

Comment: What are you using for the front end? I've built a React component to help with this. try it out with npm install bankdeets, or take a look at the demo here: http://bankdeets.co/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably do not need to search through these fields, you could use a [`serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-serialize)d text field in your model.

Set up a definition for every country, maybe as a constant hash:

```
BANK_ACCOUNT_FIELDS = {
         # use array to preserve order
  :de => [:account_holder, :account_number, :bank_number], 
  :fr => [:account_number, :bank_key, :bank_code, :branch_code]
}
```

With this you can access every field like

```
lang = @bank_account.lang # use this field to know the country settings
BANK_ACCOUNT_FIELDS[lang].each do |field_name|
  @bank_account.data[field_name] = ...
end
```

For display use partials for each language, for displaying the field names use the I18n module.